# Updating label content within a method

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to change the WPF label content within a process,
I tried this but no content change in real time. 
where am I doing wrong?

Event caller:

```
private void connect_button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
    labelStstusUpdate("Connecting.."); // Status changer
    config = new Configuration();
    bool status = config.connectViaUSB();
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
    if (!status)
    {
        labelStstusUpdate("Disconnected");// Status changer
    }
    else
    {
        labelStstusUpdate("Connected");// Status changer
    }
}
```

Status changer method:

```
private void labelStstusUpdate(string message)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (SendOrPostCallback)delegate
    {
        available_amount_label.Content = message;
    }, null);
}
```

Comment: I think you should read some articles about DataBinding and MVVM. This is not the way you should treat data.

Comment: Why are you using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke? You should only do that when updating the label from a non-UI thread.

Comment: I believe your method executes very long (`connectViaUSB`) and thus blocks the WPF UI thread ("MouseDown") - you should do this in a separate thread and then call labelStatusUpdate from within that thread.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that in WPF - the Databinding is totally different.
Basically, you have to set the Datacontext of the Window to your class and then bind the Label to a property on your class.

This would look like:

```
public class MyWindow()
{
    public string Labeltext{ get; set; }

    private void labelStstusUpdate(string message)
    {
        this.Labeltext = message
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Labeltext);
    }
}
```

When you call the Notify Method, WPF will notice the change and update the label.

As a hint: Use a mvvm framework like Caliburn.Micro for WPF design, it drasticalls reduces the amount of errors and eases the development a bit.

Comment: You "cannot" do that? That's not true. He shouldn't do it this way but he can.

Comment: @MarkGreen Call it "Educational cannot do that" - of course you *can* do it. But it is like learning a complex skill like building cars. At first: there are lots of "you cannot do that" and after a few years you discover that you can do it, but 90% of the time should not do it, because bad things happen.
So, it is better to say "you cannot do that" at first---

Answer (score 1):

This is an code from my recent application where we are changing the value of label in runtime try to find a workaround from this

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
  int Value=0;
  private delegate void UpdateMyLabel(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, Object value);

  private void Processmerge()
  {
     UpdateMyLabel updateLabelDelegate = new UpdateMyLabel(_Mylabel.SetValue);

     foreach (var item in Collections)
     {
            string _Mylabel= "Process completed..." + Value.ToString() + " %";
            Dispatcher.Invoke(updateLabelDelegate, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, new object[] { System.Windows.Controls.Label.ContentProperty, _Mylabel});

       Value++;
     }
  }
}


}
```